# Preposition for "to work on something"

Tags: prépositions

"You need to work more on your vocabulary for the next exam."

> Vous devez travailler plus ___ votre vocabulaire pour le prochain examen.

What preposition (if any) do we need? The direct translation from English would be *sur*, but [a dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/travailler) has the example *travailler son piano*, so maybe we don't need anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in this sentence indeed, you don't need any preposition.

Actually, it depends what is the "something". If its a discipline (school subject, sport, art...) I would not add anything.

However, you should use "travailler sur quelque chose" if that "quelque chose" refers to a specific task ("travailler sur un projet" par exemple).

Dont hesitate if anyone wants to bring any correction or precision :)